# Battleship game in C

Tags: c, game

Goal: Create a simple battleship game to test what I've learned so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void buff_clr(void)
{
    char junk;
    do{
        junk=getchar();
    }while(junk!='\n');
}
struct coord
{
    int y;
    int x;

}coords;

int randgen(int **ships_ptr,int n)
{
    int i,j,count=0;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            ships_ptr[i][j]=rand()%2;
            if(ships_ptr[i][j]==1)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
void draw_gui(char **pseudo_gui_ptr,int n)
{
    int i,j;

    pseudo_gui_ptr[0][0]=' ';
    for(i=1;i<(n+1);i++)
    {
        pseudo_gui_ptr[0][i]=i+48;
        pseudo_gui_ptr[i][0]=i+48;
    }

    for(i=1;i<(n+1);i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<(n+1);j++)
        {
            pseudo_gui_ptr[i][j]='+';
        }
    }
}
void battle(int **ships_ptr, char **pseudo_gui_ptr,int n, struct coord x,int* count,int* miss)
{

    int i,j;

     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(x.x-1 == i && x.y-1 == j)
                {
                    if(ships_ptr[i][j]==1)
                    {
                        if(pseudo_gui_ptr[i+1][j+1]=='O')
                        {
                            printf("\nYou've already uncovered this field!\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        printf("\nHit!\n");
                        pseudo_gui_ptr[i+1][j+1]='O';
                        (*count)--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(pseudo_gui_ptr[i+1][j+1]=='X')
                        {
                            printf("\nYou've already uncovered this field!\n\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        printf("\nMiss!\n");
                        pseudo_gui_ptr[i+1][j+1]='X';
                        (*miss)++;
                    }

                }
            }
        }


}
void result(char **pseudo_gui_ptr,int n)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<(n+1);i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<(n+1);j++)
        {
            printf("%6c",pseudo_gui_ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
int main(){

   int **ships;
   char **pseudo_gui;
   int i,j;
   int n;
   char switch_size,switch_difficulty;
   int difficulty=0;
   int shipcount=0;
   int x_count=0;


   printf("\t\t\tSink the ships v0.1b");

   printf("\nChoose size(S,M,L):");
   scanf("%c",&switch_size);
   buff_clr();

      switch(switch_size)
   {
       case 's':
       case 'S':n=3;break;
       case 'm':
       case 'M':n=5;break;
       case 'l':
       case 'L':n=8;break;
       default:printf("\nYou've choosen poorly!");
               getch();
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("\nChoose difficulty(E,H):");
   scanf("%c",&switch_difficulty);
   buff_clr();

   switch(switch_difficulty)
   {
       case 'e':
       case 'E':difficulty=(n*2)-2;break;
       case 'h':
       case 'H':difficulty=(n/2);break;
       default:printf("\nYou've choosen poorly!");
               getch();
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   ships=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));

   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       ships[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
   }

   pseudo_gui=(char**)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char*));

   for(i=0;i<(n+1);i++)
   {
       pseudo_gui[i]=(char*)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));
   }

   shipcount=randgen(ships,n);

   printf("\n\nNumber of ships to be sunk:%d",shipcount);
   printf("\nNumber of misses allowed: %d\n\n",difficulty);

   draw_gui(pseudo_gui,n);
   result(pseudo_gui,n);

   while(shipcount!=0 && x_count!=difficulty)
   {

   printf("\nEnter coordinates (x,y):");
   scanf("%d,%d",&coords.x,&coords.y);
   buff_clr();

   system("cls");

   battle(ships,pseudo_gui,n,coords,&shipcount,&x_count);
   result(pseudo_gui,n);

   printf("Number of ships to be sunk:%d",shipcount);
   printf("\nNumber of misses(out of %d): %d\n\n",difficulty,x_count);

   }
   if(shipcount==0)
   {
       printf("\nWinner!\n\n");
       getch();
   }
   else if(x_count==difficulty)
   {
       printf("\nYou Lose!\n\n");
       getch();
   }


  return 0;
}
```

This what I've made so far but i'm in doubt if my code is:

1. Easy to understand
2. Straightforward
3. Could have I done anything in a different, easier, or more convenient way?

Also, what would be the most optimal way of solving wrong input when it comes to size and difficulty? I first made the default in switch request the input again, but the problem is that it only requests twice (once for the initial request and 2nd time in the default).  I've tried to add a do-while function for `scanf`s, but it seems I can't have more than one condition (I tried adding multiple checks if input is != to the letter).

Also, could you help me pitch some ideas how I could add longer ships which would span over 2 tiles since I'm using a random generator?  I know I can check for 1's and then add code to put a 1 in (i+n) which would make a vertical ship spanning 2 tiles and for horizontal (i+1, i-1), but I would need some checks (I'm thinking of adding a few `if`s to check if I'm on n tile) to see if the 1 is by the 'edge'. However, would that work and is it the most efficient method? If not, give me an idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void buff_clr(void)
{
    char junk;
    do{
        junk=getchar();
    }while(junk!='\n');
}

struct coord
{
    int y;
    int x;

}coords;

int randgen(int **ships_ptr,int n)
```

`randgen` tells me that I'm doing some random generation. I'd include something about map in the title.

```
{
    int i,j,count=0;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
```

I wouldn't put this here. You should call this once per program, and you might generate multiple maps per program.

```
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            ships_ptr[i][j]=rand()%2;
            if(ships_ptr[i][j]==1)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
void draw_gui(char **pseudo_gui_ptr,int n)
{
    int i,j;

    pseudo_gui_ptr[0][0]=' ';
    for(i=1;i<(n+1);i++)
    {
        pseudo_gui_ptr[0][i]=i+48;
        pseudo_gui_ptr[i][0]=i+48;
```

Use '0' instead of 48 to make it clearer what you are doing

```
    }

    for(i=1;i<(n+1);i++)
```

You don't need the parens around `(n+1)`

```
    {
        for(j=1;j<(n+1);j++)
        {
            pseudo_gui_ptr[i][j]='+';
        }
    }
}
void battle(int **ships_ptr, char **pseudo_gui_ptr,int n, struct coord x,int* count,int* miss)
```

That's getting to be a rather lot of parameters. I'd put everything inside a Game or Map struct. That way you just pass one pointer, and the everything else comes as part of that.

```
{

    int i,j;

     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(x.x-1 == i && x.y-1 == j)
                {
```

What are you doing? You don't want to do anything multiple times, so you shouldn't be using a loop. You know exactly what i and j will be so just calculate those values.

```
                    if(ships_ptr[i][j]==1)
                    {
                        if(pseudo_gui_ptr[i+1][j+1]=='O')
```

Reading back the GUI is generally not helpful. What if the GUI changes? Instead, I'd have a struct Tile to hold the map. Inside would be a ship and uncovered booleans. That would make things a bit simpler

```
                        {
                            printf("\nYou've already uncovered this field!\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        printf("\nHit!\n");
                        pseudo_gui_ptr[i+1][j+1]='O';
                        (*count)--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(pseudo_gui_ptr[i+1][j+1]=='X')
                        {
                            printf("\nYou've already uncovered this field!\n\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        printf("\nMiss!\n");
                        pseudo_gui_ptr[i+1][j+1]='X';
                        (*miss)++;
                    }

                }
            }
        }


}
void result(char **pseudo_gui_ptr,int n)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<(n+1);i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<(n+1);j++)
        {
            printf("%6c",pseudo_gui_ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
```

I'd get rid of pseudo_gui_ptr and regenerate the output each time based on the Tile data.

```
}
int main(){

   int **ships;
   char **pseudo_gui;
   int i,j;
   int n;
   char switch_size,switch_difficulty;
   int difficulty=0;
   int shipcount=0;
   int x_count=0;


   printf("\t\t\tSink the ships v0.1b");

   printf("\nChoose size(S,M,L):");
   scanf("%c",&switch_size);
```

switch_size? Name it after what it means, not the control structure you are going to hand it to.

```
   buff_clr();

      switch(switch_size)
   {
       case 's':
       case 'S':n=3;break;
       case 'm':
       case 'M':n=5;break;
       case 'l':
       case 'L':n=8;break;
       default:printf("\nYou've choosen poorly!");
```

:P

```
               getch();
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("\nChoose difficulty(E,H):");
   scanf("%c",&switch_difficulty);
   buff_clr();

   switch(switch_difficulty)
   {
       case 'e':
       case 'E':difficulty=(n*2)-2;break;
       case 'h':
       case 'H':difficulty=(n/2);break;
       default:printf("\nYou've choosen poorly!");
               getch();
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   ships=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));

   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       ships[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
   }

   pseudo_gui=(char**)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char*));

   for(i=0;i<(n+1);i++)
   {
       pseudo_gui[i]=(char*)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));
   }

   shipcount=randgen(ships,n);

   printf("\n\nNumber of ships to be sunk:%d",shipcount);
   printf("\nNumber of misses allowed: %d\n\n",difficulty);

   draw_gui(pseudo_gui,n);
   result(pseudo_gui,n);

   while(shipcount!=0 && x_count!=difficulty)
   {

   printf("\nEnter coordinates (x,y):");
   scanf("%d,%d",&coords.x,&coords.y);
   buff_clr();
```

Make you indent consistently!

```
   system("cls");

   battle(ships,pseudo_gui,n,coords,&shipcount,&x_count);
   result(pseudo_gui,n);

   printf("Number of ships to be sunk:%d",shipcount);
   printf("\nNumber of misses(out of %d): %d\n\n",difficulty,x_count);

   }
   if(shipcount==0)
   {
       printf("\nWinner!\n\n");
       getch();
   }
   else if(x_count==difficulty)
   {
       printf("\nYou Lose!\n\n");
       getch();
   }


  return 0;
}
```

Overall pretty good. The only really crazy thing is the for-for-if.

> Also what would be the most optimal way of solving wrong input when it comes to size and difficulty? I first made the default in
>   switch request the input again but the problem is that it only
>   requests twice(once for the initial request and 2nd time in the
>   default) so tried to add a do-while function for scanfs but it seems i
>   can't have more than one condition(i tried adding multiple checks if
>   input is != to the letter).

Some sort of while loop is the way to go. I'm not sure exactly where you had trouble. You may want to consider asking that as a question on Stackoverflow.

> Also could you help me pitch some ideas how i could add longer ships which would span over 2 tiles since i'm using a random
>   generator. I know i can check for 1's and then add a code to put a 1
>   in (i+n) which would make a vertical ship spanning 2 tiles and for
>   horizontal(i+1, i-1) but i would need some checks(i'm thinking of
>   adding a few if's to check if i'm on n tile) to see if the 1 is by the
>   'edge'. However would that work and is it the most efficient method?
>   If not give me an idea.

I'd suggest you add a function like:

```
int is_occupied(Map * map, int i, int j)
{
    if(i < 0 || j < 0 || i > map->n || j > map->n)
        return true;
    return map.tiles[i][j].ship;
}
```

Then only place ships where is_occupied() returns false. It'll return true if there is already a ship there, or if the tile goes off the edge of the map.

**EDIT**

Here is what I'm thinking you could do with tile:

```
struct tile
{
    int ship;
    int uncovered;
};

struct game
{
    struct tile **tiles;
    char **pseudo_gui;
    int shipcount;
    int x_count;
};

void map_gen(struct game *data,int n)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            data->tiles[i][j].ship =rand()%2;
            data->tiles[i][j].uncovered = 0;
            if(data->ships[i][j]==1)
            {
                data->shipcount++;
            }
        }
    }
}
void battle(struct game *data, struct coord x)
{

    int i,j;

    Tile * tile = &tiles[x.x-1][x.y-1];
    if(tile->uncovered)
    {
        printf("\nYou've already uncovered this field!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if(tile->ship)
        {
            printf("\nHit!\n");
            data->pseudo_gui[x.x][x.y]='O';
            data->shipcount--;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nMiss!\n");
            data->pseudo_gui[x.x][x.y]='X';
            data->x_count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Other comments on update:

1. I'd make a create_game function to setup the fields in game rather then doing it main

Comment: Reading back the GUI is generally not helpful. What if the GUI changes? Instead, I'd have a struct Tile to hold the map.  Inside would be a ship and uncovered booleans. That would make things a bit simpler.

I'm afraid i don't quite get that. Create a Tile struct which would hold a ship and uncovered booleans? So basically i should create a struct out of my generated hidden field? I'm kind of confused. I did change some of the things though, i'll update the main code soon.

Comment: Whoops i butchered that comment. Anyway i updated the main post and tell me if i did anything wrong? I'm still a newbie with structs.

Comment: @MrPlow, I've added an edit that will hopefully help

Comment: a little question. What exactly is 
`Tile * tile = &tiles[x.x-1][x.y-1];`

To me it looks like a pointer to struct tiles, however the `Tile` confuses me. Where did that come from? I didn't see any typedef on tile struct so i'm kind of confused. I'm still new to structs so i hope i'm not too much of a bother

Comment: @MrPlow, I inadvertently switched into C++ writing that. It should be `struct Tile`

Comment: I'm sorry i'm just confused.

I tried doing what you've told me but i ran into some problems.
`game_data.tiles=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));` - `assignment from incompatible pointer type` and i tried adding `struct Tile *tile = &tiles[x.x-1][x.y-1]` in multiple variants such as `struct tiles *tile=&tiles[x.x-1][x.y-1]` which seems the most sensible to me. Here is my current non-working code [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/myLpkcY1) . I really like your idea so i guess it's time for me to try to learn structs

Comment: @MrPlow, you need to change the references to `int` in your malloc call to `struct tile`. `Tile` should be `tile`, I usually capitalize my struct names so I slipped back into that. And structs are very important, learn them. In fact, I recall reading that the first attempt to implement Unix in C failed because the version of C they were using didn't have structs yet.

Comment: Of course, i love programming and learning new things. I thank you for your patience, if everything goes well i'll update my code soon for your review.

Comment: Ok i think i've wrote everything as you suggested but `uncovered` does nothing. On a further note i've become a bit more confused now with the whole thing. Do i now have an array of structures consisting of `ship` and `uncovered` ? how do they come into play? As far as i can see `ship` is an array of `n` elements filled with random generated booleans while `uncovered` is a an array of `n` elements filled with 0's. I don't know the purpose of uncovered here since there is nothing to change it's value. Also how exactly does that struct now work as an array(not an exact array but a pointer)?

Comment: i edited the code in the main post. Everything works now i think. Tell me is this ok and if it's not what should i change?

Comment: @MrPlow, it looks pretty good. I'd fix the inconsistent indentation in `battle`

Comment: i added destroyer ships to medium and large maps, though i have to tweak and/or possibly remake the code. Anything i could improve?